# Select all from one table where some columns match another select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two differents tables. The have some columns in common, for this example lets say 'name' and 'id'.

By making

```
(   SELECT name,id FROM table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT name,id FROM table2)  
UNION ALL
(   SELECT name,id FROM table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT name,id FROM table1)
```

I get a list of the elements that are on one tablet but not in the other one.

Up to this point everything is OK.

But now, I want to make a select all from `table1` where the name and the id matches the result of the query above.

Comment: What do you mean select from table1 where the result matches the query above? Isn't that the query before the UNION ALL?

Comment: Yes, but I want all the columns.

Comment: Ok - updated my answer below. Let me know what you think

Comment: So wait since this insn't mySQL you could just use a `full outer join` to do this and look at records `where (T1.Id or T2.ID is null)` to ensure records from one don't exist in outer.

Comment: Please include if possible in the question mocked up data and expected results.  Where I'm struggling is if you want ID,Name columns to be reused.  I think so which is what's making this challenging.  So if a record exists in table2 but not in table 1, would you want to show it in the results?  If so then you don't just want table1 columns, you also need records from table2 to "Show" the name, ID in table2 not in table1.  If you don't need this then why do you need the union in the first place?

Comment: If you don't want records in table2 not in table 1, then why the union in your question: `UNION ALL
(   SELECT name,id FROM table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT name,id FROM table1)`?  you asked, "But now, I want to make a select all from table1 where the name and the id matches the result of the query above."  since the record in table2 not in 1 is in your result set, you don't seem to want it... or need to use it... so I'm confused.

Comment: @xQbert The left join is what I want. The last edit on the your answer is exactly whay I am looking for. I answered there my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lots of comments I think this is what you're after...

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
   on T1.ID = T2.ID
  and T1.Name = T2.Name
  AND E2.event_Time_UTC between  convert(datetime,'2016-02-09 00:00:20',101) and convert(datetime '2016-02-09 23:59:52',101)
WHERE T2.Name is null
 AND E1.Event_Time_UTC between  convert(datetime,'2016-02-09 00:00:20',101) and convert(datetime,'2016-02-09 23:59:52',101)
```

You may allow implicit casting to work but above is the explicit approach.

If not then you would need to cast the string dates to a date time, assuming Event_Time_UTC is a date/time datatype.

A left join lets us return all records from the 1st table and only those that match from the 2nd.

The t1.* returns only the columns from table1. The join criteria (on) allows us to identify those records which match so they can then be eliminated in the where clause by 'where t2.name is null'  they will always be null when no record match in t2.

Thus you get a result set that is: all records from t1 without a matching record on name and id in table2.

[image]

### Old version

The below content is no longer relevant, based on comments.

I redacted previous answer a lot because you're using SQL Server not MySQL and I know you want multiple records not table1 and table2 joined.

In the below I create two tables: table1 and table2.  I then populate table1 and table2 with some sample data

I then show how to get only those records which exist in one table but not the other; returning a separate ROW for each.  I then go into detail as to why I choose this approach vs others.  I'll finally review what you've tried and try to explain why I don't think it will work.

```
create table table1 (
  ID int,
  name varchar(20),
  col1 varchar(20),
  col2 varchar(20),
  col3 varchar(20));

Create table table2 (
  id int,
  name varchar(20));

Insert into table1 values (1,'John','col1','col2','col3');
Insert into table1 values (2,'Paul','col1','col2','col3');
Insert into table1 values (3,'George','col1','col2','col3');

Insert into table2 values (1,'John');
Insert into table2 values (4,'Ringo');
```

Option 1

```
SELECT T1.name, T1.ID, T1.Col1, T1.Col2, T1.Col3
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
 on T1.Name = T2.Name
and T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T2.ID is null  

UNION ALL

SELECT T2.name, T2.ID, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM Table1 T1
RIGHT JOIN Table2 T2   
 on T1.Name = T2.Name
and T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.ID is null  ;
```

which results in...

[image]

Notice John isn't there as it's in both tables.  We have the other 2 records from table1, and the ID, name from table2 you're after.

Normally I would do this as a full outer join but since I think you want to reuse the name and id fields to relate to BOTH tables in the same column we had to use this approach and spell out all the column names in table 1 and put NULL for each column in table1 when displaying records from table2 in order to make the output of the second query union to the first.  We simply can't use *

Option 2: Using a full outer join... with all columns from T1

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 T2
 on T1.ID = T2.ID
 and T1.Name = T2.Name
WHERE (T1.ID is null or T2.ID is null)
```

you get this...  which doesn't show Ringo...

[image]

But then I would ask why you need anything from Table 2 at all so I think you're wanting to still show the ID, Name from table2 when it doesn't exist in table1.

Which is why What I think you're after is the results from the 1st query using the union all.

***Option 3 I suppose we could avoid the second query in option 1 by doing...***

```
SELECT coalesce(T1.Name, T2.name) as name, coalesce(T1.Id,T2.ID) as ID, T1.col1, T1.Col2, T1.Col3
FROM Table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 T2
 on T1.ID = T2.ID
 and T1.Name = T2.Name
WHERE (T1.ID is null or T2.ID is null)
```

which gives us what I believe to be the desired results as well.

This works because we know we only want the name,id from table2 and all the column values in table1 will be blank.

Notice however in all cases we simply can't use Tablename.* to select all records from table1.

[image]

**This is what you tried:**

```
(   SELECT name,id FROM table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT name,id FROM table2)  
UNION ALL
(   SELECT name,id FROM table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT name,id FROM table1)
```

1. Assuming you want to reuse the ID, Name fields; you can't select *. Why? because the records in Table2 not in table1 aren't in table1.  In my example if you want Ringo to show up you have to reference table2!  Additionally, * gives you no ability to "Coalesce" the ID and name fields together as I did in option 3 above.
2. If you ONLY want the columns from table1, that means you will NEVER see data from table2. If you don't need the data from table2, (such as ringo in my example) then why do we need to do the union at all?)  I'm assuming you want ringo, thus you HAVE to somewhere reference name, id from table2.

Comment: Their structures arent identical. Thats the problem, they have some columns in common, but they have other ones that are different. I want ALL the columns from the table that has the data.

Comment: Then list the columns indivudally and put "NULL" in the 2nd select for those columns that don't exist.  you may have to alias the columns from table2 that match in table1 so you can more easily reference them but if the column count isn't that bad this would be pretty easy to do.  Or if the column count is large, simply select the columns from a system table and copy/paste them into the select...

Comment: You may want to read up on join types at [coding horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) a full outer join gives you all records from both tables matching or not, and by checking for null on the join criteria you can show where they do not intersect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, and sorry for my mistake. I want ALL the columns for the table1, asumming table1 is the one that has the rows table2 doesnt. By making the query I wrote on my initial post I already got the rows I want, but not all the columns. Am I being clear?

Comment: The lower query in my answer returns all columns from both tables for records which in Table1 not in table2 union records in table2 not in table1.  but not the rows wiht null records for table 2.  The upper query shows how you can use "NULL" keyword to union the two result sets given different number of columns. but all columns would have to be explicitly spelled out.

Comment: I dont want the columns of table2. The idea is
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE table1 and table2 do not match on name,id

Comment: Then option 1 above would work.  you'd get all columns/values from table1 and only name, id from table 2 which appear in same columns as table1 and have null values for all other columns from table 1.  If that's not what you're after then I need to see a result set and a mockup of data from table1, table2 with expected results.

Comment: I will give an example.

Lets say table2 has columns name,id,time,age. Table1 has name,id,month,season. 

I want ONLY all  the columns of table1 where name and id does not match any row of table2. 

This result will be after inserted into another table1 of another db.

Comment: @TiraULTI updated answers based on sample data i created.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will be testing this now, and update on the result.

Comment: I just saw your edit. I dont want Ringo. I dont want anything at all from table2. I just tried the query without the UNION ALL, just the first part and you are right, I dont need that part. I want the data I would get from a select * from table1 but witout the entrys that share name and id with the entrys on table2.

Comment: Then what you're after is a left join. Answer updated. at top.

Comment: I am trying to exectue this query but I cant make it work. The table1 name is EVENTS from db1, and table2 is EVENTS from db2 (They have different columns). 
`select * from EVENTS LEFT JOIN ACCESSCONTROLPOSTUP.dbo.events on events.serialnum=accesscontrolpostup.dbo.events.serialnum where accesscontrolpostup.dbo.events.serialnum is null` @xqbert

Comment: `select E1.*
from EVENTS E1
LEFT JOIN ACCESSCONTROLPOSTUP.dbo.events  E2
 on E1.serialnum=E2.serialnum 
where E2.SerialNum is null` (had an error corrected)  Alias table names for readability.

Comment: Great, that query sort of worked. The problem is, the tables are gigantic. Both tables share a column named EVENT_TIME_UTC. Lets say I want the events between  '2016-02-09 00:00:20'. and '2016-02-09 23:59:52' @xQBert

Comment: cast the string dates to the appropriate datatype for the Event_Time_UTC and add it as limiting critiera.  Since we're using a left join, we need to put the limits for E2 on the join itself.  or the left join will get treated as an inner join and we will not get the desired results... (answer updated)

Comment: THANKS!! It worked. Sorry for taking so much of your time.

Comment: Just for future reference when asking SQL related questions post table structure, sample data which illustrates the problem and SQL tried and expected results.  all of these things together help illustrate the problem and what you're trying to achieve.  my biggest problem was that you had the records from the 2nd event table not in the 1st and were not doing anything with them.. This threw me off more than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE
NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM table2
 WHERE table1.id = table2.id
 AND table1.name = table2.name)
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Thanks

Comment: For some reason this query is not giving me any row at all.

Comment: I made one update in the subquery but it shouldn't impact the results. It looks like you might already have your answer above, but if you care to share some sample data, we might be able to work through it. The query worked for me

Comment: @kbball How would this show results in table 2 not in table 1 as indicate don the second query of the  union in the original post?

Comment: @xQbert not sure I follow. My query is meant to select all fields in table 1 where the id and name combination are not together in table 2. I thought that was the question

Comment: So the 2nd part of the query in the original question gets the name, ID for all records from table2 not in table1 `(   SELECT name,id FROM table2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT name,id FROM table1)`.  I don't see how your query would include these results.

Comment: My comments are No longer relevant based on comments from OP... All he's really after is records from table1 not in table2, not the inverse.

Comment: Exactly.. It was asked in a confusing way. The unique records from table 2 are not relevant at all

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as
 (
  (   SELECT name,id FROM table1
      EXCEPT
      SELECT name,id FROM table2)  
       UNION ALL
  (   SELECT name,id FROM table2
      EXCEPT
      SELECT name,id FROM table1)
 )
 Select * 
 from table1 as tbl1
 where
    tbl1.id = cte.id
     and tbl1.name = cte.name
```

Comment: Wrapping exactly the same query in a CTE makes no difference whatsoever. Perhaps you should try to have some explanation of what you are trying to achieve and how this answer helps.

Comment: Can you please explain what cte is?

Comment: CTE is a Common Table Expression.  High level, it is a way to query against results that are returned from the query inside of the cte.  A quick google search will give you plenty of info on it.

Comment: @luke.  How would this show the records from table2 that didn't exist in table1? (the results from 2nd query in union)

Comment: Its not suppose to. From my understanding of the question posted, the user has a query that works and now they want to further query the results...

Comment: Fair enough I have a different understanding of the question, I'll seek clarification in main question comments.  Consider this: why would you union the results from table2 not in table1 and then not use them for anything?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly....Imagine the CTE as a temp table. All of the results from the query inside of the cte are stored there temporarily regardless of what table they came from. It only holds results.  Now you could alias the first query and use it as well as the second query  by just referencing them (cte.query1 or cte.query2).  The user wanted to take the results from the query and run them against the original table1. Why, that is a question for them.